# Multiple pointcuts and advices in single aspect - Spring

Tags: spring, aop

Generally @order annotation is used at the aspect level . But Where to use the @order annotation if aspect has multiple pointcuts and advices.

For example, consider the below 2 pointcuts,

```
@Pointcut("within(dao..*)")
public void creditPointcut(){}

@Pointcut("execution(* dao.*.get*(..))")
public void getDetailsPointcut(){}
```

and below 2 advices,

```
@AfterReturning(value="getDetailsPointcut()", returning= "acct")
public void afterReturning(JoinPoint point,Object acct){
   System.out.println(((Account)acct).getAccountNo());
}       

@Around("creditPointcut()") 
public void around(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable{
    LOGGER.info("Method name: "+point.getSignature().getName()+" started");
            point.proceed();            
}
```

I am getting below error,

```
Nov 16, 2015 2:21:51 PM aop.LoggerAspect around
INFO: Method name: credit started
Hibernate: update dactrainning.account set balance=balance+? where accountno=?
1000 rs credited into account :1
Nov 16, 2015 2:21:51 PM aop.LoggerAspect around
INFO: Method name: getAccountDetails started
Hibernate: select account0_.accountno as accountno0_, account0_.name as name0_, account0_.balance as balance0_ from dactrainning.account account0_ where account0_.accountno=?
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at aop.LoggerAspect.afterReturning(LoggerAspect.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:603)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterReturningAdvice.afterReturning(AspectJAfterReturningAdvice.java:58)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.getAccountDetails(Unknown Source)
    at service.impl.AccountServiceImpl.getAccountDetails(AccountServiceImpl.java:31)
    at client.DI.main(DI.java:18)
```

Can this be solved with @order here?

Comment: I think that 'acct' is null, because it's void methode.

Comment: No, this is the code @Override
 public Account getAccountDetails(int accntNo) {
  Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
  Query query = session.createQuery("from Account where accountNo=:acctNo");
  query.setInteger("acctNo", accntNo);
  Account account = (Account)query.list().get(0);
  return account;
 }

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is as follows:

1. Your query returns an empty result.
2. As a consequence, method `getAccountDetails(..)` returns `null`.
3. Finally, your advice tries to call `getAccountNo()` on a `null`object.
4. A `NullPointerException` is thrown.